# SCNShadable get transformed vertex

Tags: scenekit

Within `SCNShadable` it is straightforward to get the `u_modelViewTransform` matrix, but how do you correctly get the current vertex position after transform?

```
float4 position = u_modelViewTransform * _geometry.position;
```

The error

> program_source:443:19: error: use of undeclared identifier 'u_modelViewTransform'
>   float4 position = u_modelViewTransform * _geometry.position;

#### A bit more detail

I'm specifically, trying to get the plane equation of an `SCNPlane` this way, so maybe this is the wrong way to go?

Comment: Ii think `u_modelViewTransform` is GSLS, but you want to use the metal version `scn_node.modelViewTransform` . The apple docs are terrible, look in SCNShadable.h around line 170

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have access to `_geometry.position` where `_geometry` is of type `SCNShaderGeometry` (the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNShadable_Protocol/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Shader_Modifier_Entry_Point_Keys) for `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointGeometry`)

Comment: I found that too, it would be nice if there were more examples of this stuff. The issue is I'm trying to get the vertex after it has had the modelViewTransform applied.